# Mixed effect Cosinor model

Tags: mixed-model, cosinor

I'm interested in fitting a mixed-effect Cosinor model and am not quite sure of the correct syntax.  Reference: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3991883/

Suppose I have 30 subjects and measure hourly blood pressure.  I have within subject and between subjects I want to test.  I believe the model with no effects can be written as:

```
lmer(BP~cos((2*pi*hour)/24)+sin((2*pi*hour)/24)+(1|subject))
```

However, I'm unsure where I would specify the between and within effects in this formula.

In addition, one of the effects of interest is the amplitude:
$$
\sqrt{\hat{\beta_1}^2+\hat{\beta_2}^2}
$$
How could I compare this across effects? Is there a way with the `emmeans` packages?

**Update:**

Sample (non-sensical) code.  I would like to incorporate the between effect of age and within effect of stress_level into the model and how to test the effects of each one.

```
library(lme4)
a1 = data.frame(hour=rep(1:24,each=20),subject=rep(1:20,24),BP=rnorm(480,80,10),age=rep(rnorm(20,50,10),24),
                stress_level=sample(1:6,480,replace=TRUE))
lmer(BP~cos((2*pi*hour)/24)+sin((2*pi*hour)/24)+(1|subject),data=a1)
```

Comment: You seem to have created a new tag. Please at least add a tag wiki excerpt to say what it is & provide usage guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is an example to get the derived values such as the amplitude $\sqrt{\hat{\beta_1}^2+\hat{\beta_2}^2}$.

It demonstrates how the model fits the coefficients $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ in a linear model, which can be converted back to the coefficients in the non-linear model like the amplitude.

(provided the variance is not too large, but for the variance of the sample mean we can decrease it by taking a large enough sample).

#### Used model to generate data

To make a demonstration I have created some random data for 100 subjects. For each subject, I randomly compute the data with the following model

$$y = B + A  \sin(t +\theta) + \epsilon$$

with $t$ the time in hours multiplied by $2\pi/24$.

The parameters are random for each individual

$$ \begin{array}{}
\text{intercept} & \quad B \sim N(\mu = 80, \sigma = 2) \\
\text{amplitude} & \quad A \sim N(\mu = 10, \sigma = 3) \\
\text{phase shift} & \quad \theta \sim N(\mu = \pi/4, \sigma = 0.5) \\
\text{noise term} & \quad \epsilon \sim N(\mu = 0, \sigma = 2)
\end{array}$$

In the alternative linear model

$$y = B + \beta_1 \cos(t) + \beta_2 \sin(t) + \epsilon$$

the parameters $\beta_i$ are related to $A$ and $\theta$ as

$$\begin{array}{}
\beta_1 = A \sin(\theta) \\
\beta_2 = A \cos(\theta) \\
\end{array}$$

#### The mixed effects model

In the code below we used the line

```r
mod <- lmer(BP~1 + cos + sin + (1|subject)+ (0+cos+sin|subject), data=data)
```

this does not only make the intercept a random effect `(1|subject)` but also the parameters $\beta_i$, associated with the cosine and sine effects/terms, are now considered a random effect `(0+cos+sin|subject)`.

These random effects are placed in two separate blocks. We did not use one single `(1+cos+sin|subject)`. The reason is that the terms in a single block will be considered to be potentially correlated and the mixed-effects model will estimate the correlation. Later in the graph, we see why we want to have the `cos` and `sin` term to be correlated and in a single block.

#### Graph of data model

Below is a graph for the case of $n=100$ subjects. I set the parameter this high, while you have only 30 subjects, because with this high number it is clear that the estimates that we will compute (explained later) converge reasonably well to the values in the original model that generated the data.

[image: graphs]

With this graph for 10 subjects it is easier to see the independent lines in the left plot.

[image: graphs]

- **Overview of data with fitted model** Here you see the datapoints of all the individuals together. On top of it are fitted the fixed effects, and also the random effects for each individual.

  What you see here is that the amplitude, but also the phase of the fitted effects are different per individual subject. This occurs when we add the parameters for the cosine and sine term as a random effect with `(0+cos+sin|subject)`
- **Individual parameters** Here you see the random effects of the cosine and the sine term plotted for the individuals.

  The ellipse indicates the distribution used to model the random effects (it is the boundary containing 95% of the probability mass). The ellipse is tilted, this is possibly because we made the mixed effects model use a correlation for the two mixed effects.

  On top of the graph, we plotted isolines for the original variables (they are polar coordinates), the phase $\theta$ and the amplitude $A$. These might be the parameters that you are actually interested in.

  While the distribution of the $\beta_i$ are not really a multivariate normal distribution it could be considered to be reasonably close (if you want a better expression of the distribution then you could use a non-linear mixed effects model, where you estimate the parameters $A$ and $\theta$ instead of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$).

#### Estimation of the mean and variance of the amplitude and phase shift

The mixed effects model estimates a covariance table for the distribution of the random effects $\beta_i$ (a distribution which is assumed to be multivariate Gaussian). Based on this (approximate) distribution we can compute the distribution of the amplitude $A$ and phase shift $\theta$.

We can do this by the Delta method where we linearize the relations by a Taylor expansion. That is, a polynomial with terms $(\beta_1 - \hat{\beta}_1)$ and $(\beta_2 - \hat{\beta}_2)$ that relate to the distance from the estimates $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$.

$$\begin{array}{}
A &=&  \sqrt{\beta_1^2+\beta_2^2} \\ & \approx & \sqrt{\hat{\beta}_1^2+\hat{\beta}_2^2} + (\beta_1-\hat{\beta}_1) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\hat{\beta}_1^2+\hat{\beta}_2^2}} +  (\beta_1-\hat{\beta}_2) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\hat{\beta}_1^2+\hat{\beta}_2^2}}  \\
\theta &=& A \tan^{-1}(\beta_1/\beta_2)  \\ & \approx & \tan^{-1}(\hat{\beta}_1/\hat{\beta}_2) + (\beta_2-\hat{\beta}_2) \cdot \frac{1}{{\hat{\beta}_1^2+\hat{\beta}_2^2}} - (\beta_1-\hat{\beta}_1) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\hat{\beta}_1^2+\hat{\beta}_2^2}} 
\end{array}$$

From which we compute the mean and variance. In the code below we get the values

```r
> amp_mean
[1] 9.230997
> sqrt(amp_var)
[1] 3.285803

> phase_mean
[1] 0.7249189
> sqrt(phase_var)
[1] 0.5524258
```

which is close to the original means $10$ and $\pi/4 \approx 0.785$ and the standard deviations of $3$ and $0.5$.

#### Code example

The code below performs the computations related to the explanations above.

```r
library(lme4)

###create data for subject
getsubj <- function() {
  ### get random model variables
  offset = rnorm(1, mean = 80, sd = 2)   # offset
  amp =    rnorm(1, mean = 10, sd = 3)   # amplitude
  phase =  rnorm(1, mean = pi/4, sd = 0.5)  # phase shift
  a = amp*sin(phase)                 # cosine factor
  b = amp*cos(phase)                 # sine factor
  
  ### make model with noise
  hour = c(1:24)
  noise = rnorm(24, mean = 0, sd = 2)
  BP = offset = offset + a*cos(2*pi*hour/24) + b*sin(2*pi*hour/24) + noise
  
  ### output
  return(BP)
}


### 30 random subjects
n = 100
set.seed(1)
hour =    rep(1:24, times =n)
subject = rep(1:n, each = 24)
BP = replicate(n, getsubj())

data = data.frame(BP =  BP, hour = hour, cos = cos((2*pi*hour)/24), sin = sin((2*pi*hour)/24), subject = subject)
mod <- lmer(BP~1 + cos + sin + (1|subject)+ (0+cos+sin|subject), data=data)


### plot data
plot(hour,BP, pch = 21, col = 1, bg = 1, cex = 0.7,
     main = "overview of data with fitted model")

### fixed and random effects
t = seq(0,24,1/60)
coef =  as.matrix( fixef(mod))   # fixed
coefs = as.matrix( ranef(mod)$subject  ) + t(coef %*% rep(1,n))  # fixed + random

### plot fits per individual
for (i in 1:n) {
  coefi = coefs[i,]
  lines(t, coefi[1] + coefi[2] * cos((2*pi*t)/24) + coefi[3] * sin((2*pi*t)/24), col = rgb(0,0,0,0.5), lty = 2)
}

### plot average fit
lines(t, coef[1] + coef[2] * cos((2*pi*t)/24) + coef[3] * sin((2*pi*t)/24), col = 2, lwd= 2)


### plot coefficients
vc = as.data.frame(VarCorr(mod))
Sig = matrix(c(vc$vcov[2],vc$vcov[4],
               vc$vcov[4],vc$vcov[3]),2)
Mean = coef[2:3]

# drawMahal2 is a hack to allow edit the xlim and ylim
# chemometrics::drawMahal(coefs[,2:3],
drawMahal2(coefs[,2:3],
           center=Mean,
           covariance=Sig,quantile=0.95,
           linecol = 1,
           pch = 21 , col = 1, bg = 1, cex = 0.7,
           xlab = "cosine factor", ylab = "sine factor",
           xlim = c(-15,15), ylim = c(-18,18),
           main = "individual parameters")

### isolines for amplitude
phi = seq(0,1,0.01)*2*pi
for (i in c(5,10,15,20,25)) {
  lines(cos(phi)*i,
        sin(phi)*i, lty = 2, col = rgb(0,0.5,0))
  text(1,-i, paste0(i), cex = 0.7, pos =1, col = rgb(0,0.5,0))
}

### isolines for phase
phi = seq(0,1,1/8)*2*pi
for (j in c(1:8)) {
  i = j+1
  lines(c(0,25)*sin(phi[i]), c(0,25)*cos(phi[i]), lty = 3, col = 4)
  text(17.5*sin(phi[i]+0.1), 17.5*cos(phi[i]+0.1), bquote( .(j)/4 * pi),
       cex = 0.7, srt = -360*j/8+90, col = 4)
}

### mean
points(coef[2],coef[3], pch = 21, col = 2, bg = 2, cex = 1)


### estimating the amplitude and it's variance
amp_mean = sqrt(coef[2]^2+coef[3]^2)
da = coef[2]/amp_mean
db = coef[3]/amp_mean   
amp_var = da^2*Sig[1,1] + db^2*Sig[2,2] + 2*da*db*Sig[1,2] 
amp_mean
sqrt(amp_var)


### estimating the phase and it's variance
phase_mean = atan(coef[2]/coef[3])
da = coef[3]/amp_mean^2
db = -1*coef[2]/amp_mean^2   
phase_var = da^2*Sig[1,1] + db^2*Sig[2,2] + 2*da*db*Sig[1,2] 
phase_mean
sqrt(phase_var)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Could you comment how I could include additional variables in the model, both between and within user-effects?  (I had age and stress_level in my dummy data).  Either way I'll award the bounty for such a detailed response.

Comment: @Glen in what way are those variables supposed to influence the outcomes? I suppose that you can add them as some cross effects. This will make the $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ effectively some linear function of age and stress_level and the phase-shift $\theta$ and amplitude $A$ will be some non-linear function of age and stress_level, which you might represent with a linear approximation.

Comment: @SextusDo you suggest multiplying them with the sin and cos fixed terms?  Include in random terms if I want varying coefficients per user?

Comment: @Glen I think that it is easier if the cross-terms are only fixed effects. When you add them as random effects then the model will have more parameters to estimate (the additional variance terms for the additional random effects). The effect of adding the cross-terms as random effects is that the magnitude/variance of the random effects can differ as a function of age and stress_level. Plots for fits of curves for individuals (fitting a separate regression for individuals) can give you coefficients $\beta_i$ that you can subsequently plot versus age and stress_level to see what it looks like.